# Traverse a pedigree from child in Go

Tags: go, recursion

I have a large population pedigree (`map[int][]int`) where the key is animal and the parents (two) in the value slice. Animals with no parents will have negative integers for parents.

Secondly, I have a list of animals that I want to build their **specific** pedigrees and write to a file. All the animals in my list' pedigree should be written to the same file.

```golang
pedigree := map[int][]int{
    1:  []int{2, 3},
    2:  []int{-1, 5},
    3:  []int{6, 7},
    4:  []int{8, 9},
    5:  []int{-1, -2},
    6:  []int{8, -2},
    7:  []int{-1, -2},
    8:  []int{-1, -2},
    9:  []int{10, -2},
    10: []int{-1, 4}
}

list := []int{1, 4}
```

And what I would expect from the file written by the io.Writer:

```
  1   2   3
  2  -1   5
  3   6   7
  5  -1  -2
  6   8  -2
  7  -1  -2
  8  -1  -2
  4   8   9
  9  10  -2
 10  -1   4
```

So I need a recursive function to traverse the pedigree starting at the base animal and then continuing on all paths until parents with negative numbers are reached.

**MORE IMPORTANTLY** the animals in my list are identified as animals that cause cycles in the pedigree (animal 4 becomes a great parent of itself).

I have tried it with the following code:

```golang
type tree struct {
    sire   *tree
    dam    *tree
    animal int
    base   int
    path   []int
}

func newTree(a, s, d, b int) tree {
    return tree{
        animal: a,
        sire:   &tree{animal: s, base: b},
        dam:    &tree{animal: d, base: b},
        base:   b,
    }
}

for _, animal := range list {
    myTree = newTree(animal, pedigree[animal][0], pedigree[animal][1], 0)
    walk(myTree, written, fw) // written is a map of integers and fw is io.Writer
}

func walk(t tree, written map[int]int, writer io.Writer) tree {
    style := "%12d%12d%12d\n"
    if t.animal == t.base {
        return t
    }
    if t.base == 0 {  // for the first iteration
        t.base = t.animal
    }
    if _, ok := written[t.animal]; !ok {
        sire := t.sire.animal
        dam := t.dam.animal
        if sire == 0 {
            sire = t.base
        }
        if dam == 0 {
            dam = t.base
        }
        written[t.animal] = 0
        io.WriteString(writer, fmt.Sprintf(style, t.animal, sire, dam))
    }
    // Shift forward.
    if t.sire.animal > 0 {
        myTree := newTree(t.sire.animal, pedigree[t.sire.animal][0], pedigree[t.dam.animal][1], t.base)
        walk(myTree, written, writer)
    }
    if t.dam.animal > 0 {
        myTree := newTree(t.dam.animal, pedigree[t.dam.animal][0], pedigree[t.dam.animal][1], t.base)
        walk(myTree, written, writer)
    }
    return t
}
```

My pedigree consists of roughly 13 million animals, but I cannot get the function to stop at the right point and get a `stack overflow` panic after a few animals are done. I believe some of my problems are:

- An animal that is involved in the cycle is the base animal so I should check if `animal == base` `(1->2->3->1)`
- An animal that is involved in the cycle is **NOT** the base animal `(1->2->3->4->5->6->3)`

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can have loops in your pedigree map, you are probably falling into one such loop. That means you have to detect loops and stop building there. You can do this by changing your tree a bit.

First, you're passing the `tree` object by value, but attaching pointers to it. Pass pointers to tree around instead:

```
func walk(t *tree, written map[int]int, writer io.Writer) *tree {
}
```

A better approach might be:

```
func (t *tree) walk(written map[int]int, writer io.Writer) {...}
```

You should also add a `*parent` to the tree so you can detect loops:

```
type tree struct {
    parent *tree
    sire   *tree
    dam    *tree
    animal int
    base   int
    path   []int
}
```

Every time you create a new level, set the parent appropriately:

```
myTree := newTree(t.sire.animal, pedigree[t.sire.animal][0], pedigree[t.dam.animal][1], t.base)
myTree.parent=t
myTree.walk(written, writer)
```

Then add a function to test if you're entering a loop:

```
func (t *tree) loop(animal int) bool {
   for t!=nil {
       if t.animal==animal {
          return true
       }
       t=t.parent
   }
   return false
}
```

And check if you're entering a loop:

```
if !myTree.loop(myTree.animal) {
   myTree.walk(written, writer)
}
```

Comment: This is amazing feedback! I'll have to double check my results now, but it ran through perfectly without any errors and the smaller pedigree looks good. Thank you!!